# how to controll the timing of data transmission (receive and transmit) in xbee module

Tags: xbee, zigbee, node-xbee

In xbee module i can receive and transmit data. now my modules are receiving and transmitting data continuously(0x92 the IO index indicator). Now i want to sent data when any pin of router will go high or only then the data will be transmit to the coordinator. It will be a event base data transmission.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IC parameter(Change Detection) to configure the router xbee to transmit if there's any change in input pin(GPIO configured as input). Set it to FF to monitor all the GPIOs for any change in the inputs.

Comment: Yes. u r right. but the sampling rate IO must be set to 0. unless it will not happen...